# What is an example of experimental confirmation of Fresnel equations?

Tags: reflection, refraction, polarization

I have been reading about Fresnel equations, but I am struggling to find a single experiment where it was experimentally demonstrated that indeed polarised light follows the function predicted by Fresnel when reflected/refracted. Can anyone give some examples of scientific data where this was proven to be correct?

Comment: Huh? Measuring the Brewster angle is a standard undergraduate experiment in our labs.

Comment: [The Fresnel Equations and Brewster's Law](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~lvovsky/471/labs/fresnel_brewster.pdf)

Comment: Snell's Law is also part of the Fresnel equations.

Comment: @ProfRob thanks. I should have been clearer, I meant a plot of all traces, especially the result from refraction, not just Brewster's angle

Comment: @Farcher thanks. But this is a protocol, I was looking for a result, particularly for the refracted component. any idea on this?